# Custom cells labels and button appear only when tapped

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I am developing a Swift application. I have 2 tables which I populate them from file. My problem regards the 2nd table which displays the labels and buttons only when pressed. If I press the cell, the labels and buttons appear, as soon as I stop tapping the cell, they dissapear. I want the buttons and labels be available without being tapped.

Comment: Please add your code to the question rather than as screen shots

Comment: Please remove tag objective-c if you want the solution in swift. what you written in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your code to spawn the buttons in the `.init` of your `UITableViewCell` However you never use this initializer in your `cellFoRowAtIndexPath`

If you move the initialization of your cell in a separate function for example `configureCell()` and call that function from every initializer in the custom class. For example:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    configureCell()
}
```

Then you should have no problem

Comment: I managed to solved the problem combining your idea with mine. I dont know if  I am doing this right, but for the moment is solved my problem. In func configureCell() I am also calling `contentView.bringSubviewToFront(label)`. Also in numberOfRowsInSection i am calling configureCell().